# Is it possible for my published DLL to reference a range of versions of a dependency?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, dependency-management

I'm publishing a DLL that is an extension to a bigger library. My DLL works with any version of the bigger library from `15.2.*` to `16.1.*`. Some folks will want to use it with the other library at v15 and some folks will want to use it with v16.

As I understand, using binding redirects is **not** a solution because binding redirects aren't something I can publish inside my DLL. Binding redirects would have to be applied manually in every project by the consumers of my DLL.

Is there any way to create such a DLL output? Post-processing the IL? Is there a robust runtime assembly resolution scheme for this type of scenario?